# Cannot register commands using "node deploy-commands.js"

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanted to register my discord commands in my discord.js project. The code is correct and my spelling is right so I ran the command `node deploy-commands.js`.

The command returns with the following error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\deploy-commands.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.1
```

deploy-commands.js is to register my commands that I made and it looks like this

```
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');

const commands = [];
// Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    // Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    // Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

// Construct and prepare an instance of the REST module
const rest = new REST().setToken(token);

// and deploy your commands!
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

        // The put method is used to fully refresh all commands in the guild with the current set
        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
    } catch (error) {
        // And of course, make sure you catch and log any errors!
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. What is `deploy-commands.js`?

Comment: The error says the file was not found. Make sure you have the file name and path correct.

Comment: The file name is correct but how do I check the path?

Comment: use `console.log(foldersPath)`